# Efficient data structure for best-match lookup

Tags: performance, data-structures, match, numerical

I'm terribly sorry if this has been asked before, I searched about 30 minutes before deciding to post this and didn't find anything.

I have an array of ascending numbers with no precise stepping:

```
12.34, 103.223, 105.3, 110, 234.45, 329.11 ...
```

I get a numeric input say, for example `106.45` and I need to rapidly find the closest match in my list. In this case `105.3`.

I'm looking for an appropriate data-structure to accomplish this, if you could recommend one.

Insertion and deletion are not performance-critical, but finding the closest match is. The structure can be immutable, the data set doesn't change often.

Comment: Isn't a simple binary search (with a sorted array) good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply prefer binary search.

Comment: as I understand it, binary search would only return exact matches... am I wrong?